# Is there a way to use logic in Excel to change fonts?

Tags: excel, fonts

So I've been working with excel to change characters and colors within cells based on where numbers fall. For example when looking at values less than 10 a symbol will appear as red down arrows and values higher than 30 will be create a green up arrow. This is all well and good and I'm using the Wingdings 3 font on the cells along with various rules to change color. The problem is the middle range. I am attempting to have a circle of varying color appear when the cells being looked at contain values greater than 9 and less than 30 (currently it displays as a horizontal double headed arrow). The problem is the Wingdings 3 font does not include any circle symbols and I can't figure out how to use the Conditional Formatting to change the font based on numerical value.

Hopefully there is a fix to this so that I can continue working on this project.

Below is what my spread sheet currently produces:

Just kidding about the image I don't have enough reputation to do that yet.

Comment: Have you taken a look at conditional formatting? That seems like a much better option...

Comment: Meaning what exactly? Within the Conditional Formatting section is how I've changed the color of the symbols from green to red. In order to change the symbols from up to down arrows I have just been using the =IF functions within cells. However, there seems to be no option to set a rule that changes the font in Conditional Formatting - at least it has always been greyed out for me.

Comment: Just making sure this is what you were using compared to a formula or VBA of some sort. You didn't mentioned conditional formatting in your OP, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Yeah above I was talking about using Conditional Formatting to change the color while I was using the IF formula type to change the symbols. The problem is the symbol I want to change to is in a different font but I am unsure of a way to go about change the font by IF's or by Condi. Formatting.. Just curious if there is a way with those or something else to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so the best way to do this (for my problem) was to go into the Conditional Formatting section of Excel and instead of using the IF function by cell just use the icon sets and manage the rules associated with them. I only needed a red and green arrows and circles and with some toying around with the settings a 4 symbol icon set with my chosen shapes did the trick. It ended up being simpler than the IF logic along with rule application I was attempting at the beginning. Just know that there are few symbol choices and no way to add more in the current version of Excel.